# Usar un solo modal para recibir los datos del video que se seleccione

Tags: vue.js

Estoy haciendo el apartado de episodios de mi web y tengo problemas al tratar de mostrar el video que pertenece a ese video en el modal. Solo me toma el link del primer video que salga en la sección. En el array donde se imprime todos lo datos de cada episodio se puede ver que no son los mismos videos y que se imprime de acuerdo a cada episodio por separado como se puede ver en esta imagen.
[image: Imagen del array]
En el código esta el modal dentro del `v-for`. Ya que si lo pongo fuera de este no se como llamar al video del que se hace click. A menos que en el click se le pase el link del video pero no se como se haría para después mostrarlos en el modal.

Les voy a explicar que el modal no se imprime la cantidad de episodios que tenga. Solo una ves, ya que no se muestra en el código. Solo se muestra como un comentario vacío y cuando se da click en el video se aparece.

Ahora... este es mi code donde esta el `v-for` de los videos con el div del modal:

```
<div class="item_XBG3T" v-for="(item, index) in data.season[show_season]" :key="index">
  <div class="image_33keh lazyloaded" @click.sync="openWatch">
    <img :src="'/_assets/img/covers/episodes/' + item.backdrop" class="lazyload" :alt="item.name">
    <div class="duration_Ob58r">{{ runtime(item.duration) }}</div>
    <div class="play_2ONZn"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 55 55"><circle cx="27.5" cy="27.5" r="26.75" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.5"></circle><path fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.5" d="M20.97 40.81L40.64 27.5 20.97 14.19v26.62z"></path></svg></div>
  </div>
  <h2 class="name_hMDmw" v-if="item.episode_number >= 10"><strong>E{{ item.episode_number }}</strong> {{ item.name }}</h2>
  <h2 class="name_hMDmw" v-else><strong>E0{{ item.episode_number }}</strong> {{ item.name }}</h2>
  <div class="overview_1HUXl">{{ item.overview | truncate(125, '...') }}</div>
  <app-play-episode v-if="watchVisible" :video="item.video" :name="item.name" type="iframe" @close="closeWatch" :key="item.name"></app-play-episode>
</div>
```

La etiqueta `app-play-episode` es donde esta el modal. y el `:video="item.name"` es donde paso el link del video para poder llamarlo en el modal.

Este es todo el code del `export default`:

```
data() {
  return {
    watchVisible: false
  };
},

components: {
  'app-nav-menu': app_nav_menu,
  'app-play-episode': app_play_episode
},

computed: mapState({
  data: state => state.series.show,
  loading: state => state.series.loading
}),

beforeDestroy() {
  this.$store.commit('CLEAR_SERIES_SHOW_DATA');
},

mounted() {
  this.$store.dispatch("GET_SERIES_DETAILS", this.$route.params.id);
},

methods: {
  openWatch() {
    this.watchVisible = true;
  },

  closeWatch() {
    this.watchVisible = false;
  }
}
```

El `data: state => state.series.show,` es donde se hace el llamado al modulo donde se puede obtener los datos del array.

Ahí esta que el modal por defecto es invisible y al dar click se hace visible. La cuestión es como hacer para mostrar el video que pertenece al dicho episodio que se le de click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el div al que se le va dar click dentro del `v-for` poner esto:

```
@click="openModal(item.video, item.name)"
```

En el método open modal llamamos a los datos que queremos darles un valor despues.

```
<app-play-episode v-if="watchVisible" :video="videoplay" :name="videoname" type="iframe" @close="closeWatch"></app-play-episode>
```

El `<app-play-episode>` ponerlo fuera del `v-for` y en el `data()` lo siguiente:

```
data() {
  return {
    videoplay: null,
    videoname: null,
    watchVisible: false,
  };
},
```

En el `methods` lo siguiente:

```
openWatch(video, name) {
    this.videoplay = video;
    this.videoname = name;
    this.watchVisible = true;
  },
```

dándole un valor a los mismos.

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener atributo en tu `data` que hará referencia al video actualmente seleccionado, por ejemplo `play`; en los `props` para el componente `app-play-episode` pasar los valores de `play`.

Entonces en el `@click` pasamos el objeto `video` que esta siendo listado al método `watch`.

```
v-for(video in play_list)..
..
@click="watch(video)"
```

El método `watch` cambia el valor de `play` y  `watchVisible`

```js
watch: function(video) {
  this.play = video
  this.watchVisible = true
}
```

Para finalizar en el componente al pasar `play` uso `?.`, esto evita que de error cuando play es null (porque no se a seleccionado ningún video).

```html
<app-play-episode v-show="watchVisible" :video="play?.url" :name="play?.name" type="iframe" @close="closeWatch">
```

Ejemplo de código completo seria así, el `data.season[show_season]` en un función computada.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    watchVisible: false,
    play: null,
    show_season: 0,
    season: [[
     { name: 'video 1',
      video: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/lcZDWo6hiuI'
     }, 
     {
      name: 'video 2',
      video: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/lcZDWo6hiuI'
     }
    ]] 
  },
  computed:{
    play_list: function() {
      return this.season[this.show_season]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    whatch: function(video) {
       this.play = video
       this.watchVisible = true
    },
    closeWatch: function() {
      this.watchVisible = false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
<!-- Listo los video -->
<ul>
 <li v-for="video in play_list">
  {{ video.name }}
  <button @click="whatch(video)">Play</button>
 </li>
<ul>
<button @click="closeWatch">Close All</button>

<!--- Agrego el componente modal -->
<app-play-episode v-show="watchVisible" :video="play?.url" :name="play?.name" type="iframe" @close="closeWatch">
  <!-- ejemplo de lo que contendria el modal-->
 {{ play?.name }}
 <iframe :src="play?.video"></iframe>
</app-play-episode>

</div>
```